Create a proper dataframe from an existing dataframe in Python?
I have a dataframe df1 and df2 like below:
|findings|jinkings|org|
|hij|NaN||
|name|place|org1|
|A1|M1|fgi|
|A2|M2|yhi|
|A3|M3|vfh|
|name|place|kij|
|A4|M4|lik|

Expected dataframe -
|name|place|
|A1|M1|
|A2|M2|
|A3|M3|
|A4|M4|

df2-
|hij|NaN||
|name|place|org1|
|A1|M1|fgi|
|A2|M2|yhi|
|A3|M3|vfh|
|A4|M4|lik|

Expected dataframe -
|name|place|
|A1|M1|
|A2|M2|
|A3|M3|
|A4|M4|

col_list = ['name','place','organization']

I want this dataframe to keep column names from columns that are passed in col_list, and start values from there the 0th index of the dataframe and remove any duplicate column names if any in dataframe.

you can drop rows that have unwanted stuff (like 'name') in findings to solve this issue:
# drop rows with name in findings
df1 = df1[~df1['findings'].str.contains('name')]
print(df1)

you can also filter for the A1, A2 etc by using:
df2 = df1[df1['findings'].str.contains('A\d')]


I have multiple dataframes , and every dataframe has different columns in it, it will not always be findings or name always in the dataframe, can we get some generic solution for it?

Then it seems your question does not reflect the full extent of your problem. It might be best to add it to the question in order to get a proper answer.

You can check the edited question now

@jezrael, can you please help me in this question?

@emileymille see it the update helps.

Try the below code:
col_list=["name","place","org1"]

indices=df[(df.iloc[:, 0]==col_list[0]) & (df.iloc[:, 1]==col_list[1]) &  (df.iloc[:, 2]==col_list[2])].index
df_new=df.iloc[indices[0]+1:,:]
df_new.columns=col_list

The above solution will work when all elements in list are found in one of the rows of dataframe
Based on your updated question, please see the answer below:
import Levenshtein as lev
col_list=["name","place","organization"]
col_string=''.join(col_list)  #creates a string var named "col_string" by joining all list elements

df['new']=df.values.sum(axis=1) # creates a new column by joining all columns
df['string_to_find']=col_string # creates a new column "string_to_find" and fills it with string var "col_string"

df["LevScore"] = df[['new','string_to_find']].apply(lambda x: lev.distance(x['new'],x['string_to_find']), axis=1) # calaculates levenstein distance between two new columns 
print(df)


indices=df.loc[df['LevScore']==df['LevScore'].min()].index #finds index of min lev distance
df_new=df.iloc[indices[0]+1:,:].drop(columns=['new','string_to_find','LevScore']) #filters all rows from min lev distance to the end.


df_new.columns=col_list
print(df_new)


if we have more number of elements in col_list around 20 elements, then it would be difficult to match like this , is there any generic way ?

getting error here - IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

@emileymille, this error occurs when the condition that matches rows against list elements is not true. You may need to check spelling and case against what is given in dataframe
